# How can Prometheus dynamically discover Google Cloud Run services?

Tags: prometheus, google-cloud-run

I'm programmatically deploying Cloud Run services using a Kubernetes Operator. The services expose Prometheus metrics.

I'm struggling to determine a good way to have Prometheus servers discover these services.

Though it seems elegant, using services with `ExternalName` and ServiceMonitors it is not possible with Prometheus Operator ([issue](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/issues/3204)). Using this approach, the Operator could have created ServiceMonitors once it obtained endpoints from deploying Cloud Run services.

There's no Prometheus service discovery mechanism for Cloud Run services. I found a dated [example](https://github.com/m-lab/gcp-service-discovery) that discovers App Engine services and could possibly be extended to Cloud Run but this uses file-based discovery.

Today, I tried to use CoreDNS and `dns_sd_config`, thinking I could program CoreDNS and have it provide a dynamic list of services to Prometheus, but IIUC, this would also require persisting changes to a (Core)file and it adds complexity.

I'm not opposed to file-based discovery but it feels "lacking". Even if done with a ConfigMap, I sense I'd need to be forcing Prometheus reloads on changes.

Particularly when lined up against the elegance of the Prometheus Operator, it feels as though I'm missing something obvious.

Should I use Consul?

> **UPDATE** I have a working configuration using Consul. Consul was easy to understand and get working.

In summary, I'd like a service with an endpoint that Prometheus could scrape to determine a list of targets. The service should be programmable to add|remove targets from the list.

Comment: Can you provide more details about how you achieved it?

Comment: Nevermind, found your blog post https://pretired.dazwilkin.com/posts/210419 :)